# Retrieve selected columns of a 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to retrieve selected columns of a 2 dimensional array, I have a 2 dimensional array

```
var indexes = [2,3,5];
var data = [
["Head1","Head2","Head3","Head4","Head5", "Head6"],
[10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
[20,21,22,23,24,25,26],
[30,31,32,33,34,35,36],
];
```

The expected is

```
var result = [
[13,14,16],
[23,24,26],
[33,34,36],
]
```

How do I get the result array, while I must be able to dynamically change the index array of positions.

I have tried to remove the first Header

```
data.shift();
```

Comment: why is index 2 13?

Comment: Where? var indexes = [2,3,5];

Comment: why is 13 on index 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With right indices, you could map the values.

```js
var indices = [2, 3, 5],
    data = [["Head1", "Head2", "Head3", "Head4", "Head5", "Head6"], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]],
    result = data.slice(1).map(a => indices.map(i => a[i]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
var indices = [2, 3, 5],
    data = [["Head1", "Head2", "Head3", "Head4", "Head5", "Head6"], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]],
    result = data.slice(1).map(function (a) {
        return indices.map(function (i) {
            return a[i];
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: => operator cannot be used in Apps script. So could you help me without => operator. Thank you so much.

Comment: you could use the standard `function`. please see edit.